# Better way to convert weights to range using map or fold?

Tags: scheme, racket, fold, higher-order-functions, map-function

Is there a shorter ⁄ better way of writing the following?
There's probably some library that does the conversion but I am wondering if some kind of
*map* or *fold* could work?

```
(define (weights-to-range lw)
  ; '(1 4 6 6 6 6 6) -> (1 5 11 17 23 29 35)
    (define (f x lw acc)
    (if (null? lw)
        acc
        (let ([y (+ x (car lw))])
          (f y (cdr lw) (append acc (list y))))))
  (f (car lw) (cdr lw) (list (car lw))))
```

Comment: I guess the initial 0 in the output is implied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Racket I would probably write it using the `for/fold` list comprehension:

```
(define (weights-to-range weights)
  (define-values (xs _)
    (for/fold ([xs '()] [prev 0])
              ([weight (in-list weights)])
      (define this (+ prev weight))
      (values (cons this xs) this)))
  (reverse xs))

(require rackunit)
(check-equal? (weights-to-range '(1 4 6 6 6 6 6))
              '(1 5 11 17 23 29 35))
```

It would be even simpler except that, since this supplies two accumulation values to the `fold/fold` --  `xs` and `prev` -- the `for/fold` form is going to return two values. So we need to tuck both into temporary vars using `define-values`, before passing the one we care about -- from `xs` -- to `reverse`. (The var for `prev` is named `_`. That's just a convention meaning "ignored", because we don't need it.)

---

Of course, the general idea here is to "fold" a list using a "sliding window" of pairs, with the cumulative result so far available to each step. In your case, the function is `+`, but it could be generalized:

```
(define (fold-slide f vs)
  (define-values (xs _)
    (for/fold ([xs '()] [prev 0])
              ([v (in-list vs)])
      (define this (f prev v))
      (values (cons this xs) this)))
  (reverse xs))
```

With such a `fold-slide` (for lack of a better name) function, you could have written simply:

```
(fold-slide + '(1 4 6 6 6 6 6)
```

Such a `fold-slide` might be even more useful if it could handle "windows" of any size, not just 2.

p.s. It's entirely possible there is some SRFI that does something like this, or a more-elegant way to do it in Racket, that I don't know.

Comment: I gave it a try and I came up with this exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to have an accumulator while still building your answer directly (that is, instead of accumulating a reversed answer and then reversing it at the end).

```
;; weights-to-range : (listof number) -> (listof number)
;; Returns list of partial sums of input list.
(define (weights-to-range lw0)

  ;; helper : (listof number) number -> (listof number)
  ;; acc is the sum of elements seen so far
  (define (helper lw acc)
    (cond [(null? lw)
           null]
          [else
           (let ([new-acc (+ acc (car lw))])
             (cons new-acc (helper (cdr lw) new-acc)))]))

  (helper lw0 0))
```